# Turn ajax data into array?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, foreach

I'm adding data to a database and I need a new ID for each element, the element's ID gets passed into ajax data...

```
    $( ".silly-string" ).draggable({
    containment: '#_moon_static_bg_status',

     stop: function(event, ui) {
         var pos_x = ui.position.left;
         var pos_y = ui.position.top;
         var divid = ui.helper.attr("id");

         jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: window.ajaxurl,
            data: { "action": "myAjax", id: divid, x: pos_x, y: pos_y }}).done(function( msg ) {
                $('.silly-string').text(msg)

         });    
      }  
});
```

The data is only sent when the drag function happens (so I think maybe the data needs to be created somewhere else?)... Let me show you an example of the HTML

```
    echo '<div class="silly-string draggable" id="silly"style="left: '.$x.'px; top: '.$y.'px;"></div>';

    echo '<div class="silly-string draggable" id="silly2"style="left: '.$x.'px; top: '.$y.'px;"></div>';

    echo '<div class="silly-string draggable" id="silly3"style="left: '.$x.'px; top: '.$y.'px;"></div>';
```

I am going to make those IDS dynamic so when user clicks add new element the ID will increment ex. every time add new is clicked a new div will be created the id will be silly + 1, so if there are 10 elements the tenth will have an ID of silly10, hope that makes sense?

Take a look at the .draggable/ajax code above you see the var divid, that takes the id of each div with the class `.silly-string` so looking at the console log it does have an out put each ID..

What I am trying to achieve is adding the data to a database, where I create a new row for each ID, but overwrite each row that has already been created with that ID...Let me show an example to make some sense of what I just said...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIPQM.jpg

You see I have a new row for silly, and silly2... the only reason I do is because I manually changed the ID 100 & 101.. but I need to change the id to be dynamic, let me show you an example..

```
      global $wpdb;


    //The data here comes from an ajax call
    $_POST['x'];
    $_POST['y'];
    $_POST['id']; 

    $term_id = 100; 
    $name = $_POST['id']; 
    $slug = $_POST['x'];
    $term_group = $_POST['y']; 

    //Im adding into wp_terms a default table (for testing)... 
    $query = "INSERT INTO $wpdb->terms (term_id, name, slug, term_group) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"; 

    //Here I insert the ajax data into the columns 
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare($query, $term_id, $name, $slug, $term_group));

    $wpdb->update("$wpdb->terms", array('slug' => $_POST['x'], 'term_group' => $_POST['y']), array('name' => $_POST['id']));

    die();
```

Here I am adding data to a database... Notice the variables `$name` and `$slug` are dynamic based on the ajax data... and when I run the update `$wpdb->update("$wpdb->terms", array('slug' => $_POST['x'], 'term_group' => $_POST['y']), array('name' => $_POST['id']));` it works fine for one element, I overwrite the slug, with the new data... if I make the `$term_id = 100;` dynamic then it defeats my purpose of not creating a new row everytime the x & y values change, because YES it does create a new ID but it changes the id to a new id each time...

Now that you're up to speed with what I have going on (hope that wasn't to long and made sense) would I need to create a new ajax variable to pass, or would I need to create a foreach statement? ex.

```
   foreach($_POST['id'] as $key => $value) {
     //Stuff
   }
```

or auto increment the variable in the ajax.. I mean I really am lost at this part and am open to some more experienced folks opinions and solutions.. could save me a lot of headache...

Let me know if you need me to specify anything its hard to print out what exactaly I see in my code and my logic, but I did the best I could

**Following @MH- solution the table looks like this**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO0AM.jpg

It still adds a new row, when the element is dragged... here is how I implemented the code in my script, perhaps I did it wrong?

```
   global $wpdb;


    //The data here comes from an ajax call
    $_POST['x'];
    $_POST['y'];
    $_POST['id']; 


    $name = $_POST['id']; 
    $slug = $_POST['x'];
    $term_group = $_POST['y']; 

    $myrows = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT id FROM {$wpdb->terms} WHERE name LIKE '{$name}'" );
       if( $myrows != null ){
    $term_id = $myrows->id;
         $wpdb->update("$wpdb->terms", array('slug' => $_POST['x'], 'term_group' => $_POST['y']), array('name' => $_POST['id']));
       } else {
         //Im adding into wp_terms a default table (for testing)... 
         $query = "INSERT INTO $wpdb->terms (term_id, name, slug, term_group) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"; 

         //Here I insert the ajax data into the columns 
         $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare($query, $term_id, $name, $slug, $term_group));
    }

    die();
```

Looking at the image... where silly and silly 2 is.. there should only be one row for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **primary key** is confusing. You want the `sillyXX` to be Unique. ( This is the requirement of not creating extra rows ). That means that you need to check if a row with `sillyXX` exists already. So you could use `sillyXX` as your **PK**.

There are a few ways of doing this. You can `select ... where`. Thinking about it, this is the only real way. If you want to use a different way you might as well just make the **PK** `sillyXX`. ( I could explain but it's not strictly relevant now).

So, before you `$query = "INSERT INTO $wpdb->terms (term_id, name, slug, term_group) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)";`, your going to want to call this.

```
$myrows = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT id FROM {$wpdb->terms} WHERE name LIKE '{$name}'" );
if( $myrows != null ){
    $term_id = $myrows->id;
    // This is an old row. Call Update.
} else {
    // This is a new row. Call Insert.
}
```

This should work / get you on the right track. If not you are going to have to clarify your questions.

Comment: Ok sorry I found out why it was disappearing... did I execute the code properly though?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean?